# Filter array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
    const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "stuffed chicken is tasty as anything",
        picture: "./img/chicken.jpg",
        tags: ["oooo", "tasty", "stuffed"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "noodles with shrimp and salad",
        picture: "./img.ramen.jpg",
        tags: ["noodles", "shrimp", "salad"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "oooooooooooooooooooooooo",
        picture: "oooooooooooooooooooo",
        tags: ["oooo", "xxxx", "qqqq"]
    }
    ];
```

So i need to find matching title: and tags: from an array. Below i show how i do it for titles.

```
let matches = data.filter(el => {
 return el.title.match(regex);
}
```

But how do i do that on tags? I could just do:

```
return el.tags[0].match(regex) || el.tags[1].match(regex);
```

But what if there is more tags? I trie to loop over it and match regex but i get empty objects.

```
return el.tags.forEach(it => it.match(regex));
```

Comment: Try [`el.tags.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `forEach`.  That will return a Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just searching using a regex, in which case you could just search the tags using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Like this:

```js
let matches = data.filter(e => e.title.match(regex) && e.tags.some(t => t.match(regex));
// --
let matches = data.filter(e => e.title.match(regex) && e.tags.every(t => t.match(regex));
```

Given they're tags and not full titles, I would suggest the `some` function. Semantically, I think it makes more sense. You wouldn't want to hide something when you've selected 1/4 of its tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `every` function of array in javascript. It will return true only when all the array elements satisfy the condition.

```
return el.tags.every(it => it.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've posted using the double pipe `||`, you should use the function `Array.prototype.some` which evaluates the predicate (aka handler) and returns true if at least one element satisfies the condition.

Additionally, you should use the function `test` instead.

```js
const data = [{    id: 1,    title: "stuffed chicken is tasty as anything",    picture: "./img/chicken.jpg",    tags: ["oooo", "tasty", "stuffed"]  },  {    id: 2,    title: "noodles with shrimp and salad",    picture: "./img.ramen.jpg",    tags: ["noodles", "shrimp", "salad"]  },  {    id: 3,    title: "oooooooooooooooooooooooo",    picture: "oooooooooooooooooooo",    tags: ["oooo", "xxxx", "qqqq"]  }];

let regex = new RegExp("[oo]");
let matches = data.filter(({title, tags}) => regex.test(title) || tags.some(t => regex.test(t)));
console.log(matches);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```